# Enter current date into a cell when another cell is changed in the same row BUT not with activeCell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Here is my problem:
I want to enter current date in column "H" (for example) when value in column "A" is changed. Currently I have this code:

```html
function onEdit(e) {
   var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
   var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
   var row        = activeCell.getRow();
  
   if (col == 1) {
     sheet.getRange(row, 7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s');
  }
}
```

And obviously it works when I myself change value in column "A". Unfortunately it does not suffice to my use, because I have connected google sheets with LiveCall bot and it copies values without activating cells.

So what I want to achieve:
If value in column "A" changes by itself (without activating cells) - enter date... Unfortunately I cannot do it another way so I want to ask you if you know any.

Comment: No triggers (simple or installed) are activated if the origin of the event is a script action. Instead, modify the source script to achieve the desired goal, or switch to a polling style (i.e. repeatedly check for changes and proceed if changes observed).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) of which there are examples on SO.